# Crash in invoking a method of a sub class object that got initialized from super class

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I have two classes  Class1 and Class2. Class2 is inherited from Class1.Class2contains a update method which is not present in Class1.

I found a crash in ios 7 - [Class1 update]  unrecognized selector sent to instance.
 This is not reproducible.
 Can any one suggest what is wrong in my code invocation.

```
+(Class1*)sharedobject{
static dispatch_once_t once;
static Class1 *sharedView;
dispatch_once(&once, ^ { 
 sharedView = [[self alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 
});
return sharedView;}

Class2: Class1{

-(void)update {
}
}

Class2 *obj = [self sharedobject];
```

[obj update];

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `sharedobject` returns an object of Class1. You said that the `update` method only exists in Class2. Yet you have written `Class2 *obj = [self sharedobject];` and then tried to call `update` on it. You have called a method on an object of Class1 that doesn't exist in Class1. That is why you have received an unrecognized selector exception.

Comment: + (A1*)sharedView{
    
   A1 *sharedView= [super sharedView];
    return sharedView;
    
} Do I need to override some thing like above in A2 class to avoid run time exception